# Command line with blender

Tags: blender, collada, vrml

I'm looking for a Command line in Blender to convert a VRML file to a Collada one

Does anyone know how to do it ?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56009/how-can-i-convert-a-file-with-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any command line options to perform that task directly. You can tell blender to run a python script from the command line, I'm not 100% certain but you should be able to run the import/export automatically through a script. If you only have a small number of files to convert then it may be easier to import and export manually. The `-b` option tells blender to run in the background so it doesn't start the gui

```
blender -b -P myscript.py
```

The x3d/vrml2 import addon should be enabled by default but if not you can enable it in the user preferences under addons.

Support for OpenCollada should be available in the official downloads, it can only be enabled/disabled at build time so if the collada export option isn't available you will need to find a build that has OpenCollada support enabled.

You can also find more help with blender specific topics at [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)